# __class__ equality check from two different imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-importlib

I have a rather complicated import setup in my python software project where I don't get around importing some modules dynamically with importlib.
Therefore I run into situations where I have two objects of the same class, but since they have been loaded independently the equality check between them gives me `False`.

Their string representations of each object's `obj.__class__` look the same:
`<class 'drivers.MongoDriver'>` vs `<class 'drivers.MongoDriver'>`.
Equality checks with `__eq__` on both classes, `issubclass`, `__eq__` on `type()` and `isinstance` fail, though.

I could think of a hacky way to still do a equality check by comparing `repr(obj.__class__)`, but that doesn't really seem so nice.
Another solution would be to "hide" an attribute specifying some unique class id.

Is there another (better) way how to do equality checks between two classes that are essentially the same but have been loaded by `importlib` independently?

Edit:
Important: I'm not looking for a way to avoid importing the class twice.
Some modules of my project are reimported on purpose dynamically to account for code changes in those modules during runtime.
Those modules then again import other modules, such as the driver I want to make an equality check with. And even though it would be nice to not have to reimport those non-changing modules that are used by the changing modules, I am aware that whenever I dynamically import one module that all dependencies are then reimported as well. (If you have a solution on how to reimport a module A which itself has a (static) import B, but not have to reimport B together with A, I would be happy. But this is not directly what I'm asking/looking for.)

Comment: How about not loading the same module twice to begin with? Solve the X instead of the Y.

Comment: _where I don't get around importing some modules dynamically with importlib_, please read my post properly

Comment: Well, those classes are not really the same class, exactly because you imported them separately. You could, for instance, do `drivers.MongoDriver = decorate(drivers.MongoDriver)` and it would modify only one of them. You should really avoid cause rather than the consequences.

Comment: BTW, you did not really explain how it happens that your class is imported twice, so we cannot help you avoid the problem.

Comment: They are imported twice because some modules are reimported on purpose (on code changes). Not the drivers themselves, but the modules that are reimported import those drivers.
I am fully aware that they really are not the same classes, I'm rather looking for a workaround since I can't change much on the dynamic imports.
Those are simply an intended part of the software